# Right Aligned elements shifted downwards

Tags: html, css, sass

I have some elements placed on left side and some on the right.

But the right aligned elements are positioned downwards and not in the same line as the left side elements.

[image]

```css
.mat-table-container {
  position: relative;
}

.mat-table-container .mat-table-button-wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.mat-table-container .mat-table-button-wrapper #left-aligned-wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.mat-table-container .mat-table-button-wrapper #right-aligned-wrapper {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mat-table-container">
  <div class="mat-table-button-wrapper">
    <div id="left-aligned-wrapper">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"> 
                Left Button
            </button>
    </div>
    <div id="right-aligned-wrapper">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
      </mat-form-field>
      <button type="button" mat-button>
              Right Button
            </button>
      <button class="btn btn-default">
              <i class="my-icon my-icon-filter"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5r6u3p-nabsuj

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce based on your supplied code.

Comment: @Paulie_D What are you getting?

Comment: @Paulie_D Please refer to this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5r6u3p-nabsuj

Answer (score 0):

In those kinds of cases I like to use `display:flex` option it is very helpful,

my solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5r6u3p-6zfzaj

the change i made was in datepicker-value-example.css i used flex to vertically align the the button and the date picker, and used margin-right/margin-left:auto to make them stick to the right and the left.

if you dont know what display flex is, you can have a good read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

**This code can help you...**

```css
.mat-table-button-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="mat-table-button-wrapper">
    <div id="left-aligned-wrapper">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"> 
                Left Button
            </button>
    </div>
    <div id="right-aligned-wrapper">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
      </mat-form-field>
      <button type="button" mat-button>
              Right Button
            </button>
      <button class="btn btn-default">
              <i class="my-icon my-icon-filter"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```